# -webkit-border-radius not work in Chrome Version 44.0.2403.89 m

Tags: css, google-chrome

Today, I faced a issue with -webkit-border-radius in Chrome Browser Version 44.0.2403.89 m.

I called border-radius first and after -webkit-border-radius is called. In firefox had no issue but i suprised the chrome has a issue

**Not working code:**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

So I change the code to call border-radius after -webkit-border-radius, it works. Can you anybody explain the issue occur.

**Working code:**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Edit:**

Now i use

```
   border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
```

Its works. How?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Edit:**

it's a bug of chrome

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.a {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
}
.b {
  background-color: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px;
}
.c {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
.d {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
}
.e {
  background-color: green;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  background-color: green;
  <br />border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />-moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />-webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />
</div>
<div class="b">
  background-color: green;
  <br />-moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />-webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />
</div>
<div class="c">
  background-color: green;
  <br />border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  <br />-moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  <br />-webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  <br />
</div>
<div class="d">
  background-color: green;
  <br />border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />-moz-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />-webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px;
  <br />
</div>
<div class="e">
  background-color: green;
  <br />-moz-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  <br />-webkit-border-radius: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D hits the nail on the head. If he posted that as an answer, I'de _sooo_ upvote. [Ahem. Just realised that the italics look sarcastic. I'm keeping them in, but I'm being honest here.]

Comment: @Paulie_D Check my edit. I add the unprefix border-radius at top and value as `0px 30px 0px 30px`, its works in chrome. How? but   `0px 30px`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unprefixed version should **always** be last in the order.

In fact, Chrome has been unprefixed for `border-radius`since at least V31.

Source: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

What do I *think* happened?

Chrome choked on a prefixed `border-radius` property that it didn't understand so it ignored it. What's interesting is that it didn't fall back to the version that it did understand...which is where my first statement comes into play.

The advice has always been...unprefixed **last**.

Comment: Check my edit. I add the unprefix border-radius at top and value as 0px 30px 0px 30px, its works in chrome. How? but 0px 30px

Comment: Fact is...my main point remains...you have the declarations in the **wrong order**. You can report it as a bug to Chrome Dev Team if you like but it's not really a bug as such...just an error in your implementation.

Comment: @Paulie_D Allow me to disagree. With the declaration in the OP's original order, the browser is supposed to either recognise the prefixed version, in which case the whole thing just works, or to ignore the prefixed version (using the unprefixed one) in which case it also works. So if it doesn't, it's most definitely a bug in the browser. The prefixed version is not supposed to start behaving differently from the unprefixed one all of a sudden!

Comment: @TamilSelvan If you use _only_ the prefixed version, or _only_ the unprefixed one, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Paulie_D I forgot to mention that the rule of putting the unprefixed version last, while not bad practice in any case, is only _really_ necessary in cases where the prefixed version works differently (like with gradients).

Comment: @MrLister All valid points...so the answer is, I suppose, *it's a bug*